# No highgui in python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to write some programs using opencv and python. I installed opencv and the python libraries from the repositories. I'm using ubuntu 12.04. The folder `/var/lib/python-support/python2.7` contains just 5 files :

- cv2.so
- cv.py
- cv.pyc
- simplegeneric-0.7.egg-info
- simplegeneric.py
- simplegeneric.pyc

From what reading I have done, I think there's supposed to be an `opencv` folder around here. I'm able to import cv library using

```
    import cv
```

but

```
    from opencv import cv
```

And I cannot load the highgui module. Any way to work around this? I would really really like to do something in opencv

Comment: Oops sorry!!! I thought it was evident. I want to know how i can import highgui module. I tried from opencv import highgui and import highgui. And as I have mentioned earlier, there doesnt seem to be any 'opencv' among my installed modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have installed OpenCV >= 2.3.1. In OpenCV 2.3.1 and higher, Python bindings do not have highgui.

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
```

and you're good to go.

```
import cv2
img  = cv2.imread("image name")
cv2.imshow("window name", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

You can find more help on [OpenCV docs](http://docs.opencv.org/) and you could also look at some of the opwncv stuff that I have been doing [here](http://jayrambhia.wordpress.com/tag/opencv).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Using cv2 version 4.0.0, second import line gives ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2.cv' . Perhaps there has been some shuffling in the cv2 namespace?

Answer (score 0):

You will get the highgui file in OpenCV folder(installed folder) in include/opencv/highgui.h.